# How to Group Data by Time Period in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I need to get  the count of records using PostgreSQL from time `7:00:00 am` till next day `6:59:59 am` and the count resets again  from `7:00am to 6:59:59 am`.

Where I am using backend as java (Spring boot).

The columns in my table are

- id (primary_id)
- createdon (timestamp)
- name
- department
- createdby

How do I give the condition for shift wise?

Comment: what is your attempt so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to pick a slice based on the current time-of-day (I am assuming this to be some kind of counter which will be auto-refreshed in some application).

One way to do that is using time ranges:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
WHERE createdon <@ (
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN current_time < '07:00'::time THEN
            tsrange(CURRENT_DATE - '1d'::interval + '07:00'::time, CURRENT_DATE + '07:00'::time, '[)')
        ELSE
            tsrange(CURRENT_DATE + '07:00'::time, CURRENT_DATE + '1d'::interval + '07:00'::time, '[)')
        END
)
;
```

Example with data: https://rextester.com/LGIJ9639

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, you need to have a separate group for values in each 24-hour period that starts at 07:00:00.

```sql
SELECT
    (
        date_trunc('day', (createdon - '7h'::interval))
            + '7h'::interval
    ) AS date_bucket,
    count(id) AS count
FROM lorem
GROUP BY date_bucket
ORDER BY date_bucket
```

This uses the [date and time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) and the [GROUP BY clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY):

- Shift the timestamp value back 7 hours (`(createdon - '7h'::interval)`), so the distinction can be made by a change of date (at 00:00:00). Then,
- Truncate the value to the date (`date_trunc('day', …)`), so that all values in a bucket are flattened to a single value (the date at midnight). Then,
- Add 7 hours again to the value (`… + '7h'::interval`), so that it represents the starting time of the bucket. Then,
- Group by that value (`GROUP BY date_bucket`).

---

A more complete example, with schema and data:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lorem;
CREATE TABLE lorem (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    createdon timestamp not null
);

INSERT INTO lorem (createdon) (
    SELECT
        generate_series(
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '36h'::interval,
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + '36h'::interval,
           '45m'::interval)
);
```

Now the query:

```sql
SELECT
    (
        date_trunc('day', (createdon - '7h'::interval))
            + '7h'::interval
    ) AS date_bucket,
    count(id) AS count
FROM lorem
GROUP BY date_bucket
ORDER BY date_bucket
;
```

produces this result:

```
     date_bucket     | count 
---------------------+-------
 2019-03-06 07:00:00 |    17
 2019-03-07 07:00:00 |    32
 2019-03-08 07:00:00 |    32
 2019-03-09 07:00:00 |    16
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation -- by subtracting 7 hours:

```
select (createdon - interval '7 hour')::date as dy, count(*)
from t
group by dy
order by dy;
```

Comment: That will just put the timestamp 7 hours back and not correlate it to any 24-hour-slice as the OP requires to handle. In addition, subtracting 7 hours does not relate to 7 o'clock.

Comment: @Ancoron . . . You are right.  I added the intended conversion to `date`.